# what does reportFailure method actually do in a custom ExecutionContext

Tags: scala

I wrote this code

```
val myEc = new ExecutionContext {
    val tp = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
    def execute(r: Runnable) { tp.submit(r) }
    def reportFailure(t: Throwable) { println("ho ha ha ... something broke!") }
}

val f : Future[Int] = Future(throw new Exception("123"))(myEc)
Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```

The program doesn't print "ho ha ha"... so what is the purpose of reportFailure then? shouldn't it get called when the future fails?

Comment: I think result is in future and you are not trying to access the value inside future you are just waiting for the future to be complete by await.

Comment: Can you answer with code. I'm not clear with what you are trying to say. f is not Future of Future. it is just Future of Int.